# Binding Interfaces to Implementations in Eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, module, interface

According to "[binding-interfaces-to-implementations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations)" it is possible to bind an interface with its implementation, as follows:

```
$this->app->bind(
    'App\SharedContext\Userable',
    'App\Modules\Core\User'
);
```

So when I call the next line, I will get an `User` object:

```
$user = $this->app->make(Userable::class);
```

**However...** when I try to do the same process with an Eloquent relationship:

```
/**
 * Returns the user who created this... whatever. (I wish it worked! )
 *
 * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function creatorUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Userable::class, 'created_by');
}
```

it, *obviously*, gives me the following error:

```
⛔⛔⛔ Cannot instantiate interface App\SharedContext\Userable
```

The same error if I try to instance an interface as follow:

```
$anInterfaceCannotBeInstantiateFool = new Userable();
```

I think there should be a way to delegate to an abstraction (*interface*) instead of using a concrete class. In this way it would be much easier to modularize the application and make it more decoupled.

### Has anyone done something similar in Laravel?

Comment: You can't instantiate the concrete class of an interface using `new`, you have to do it via the container. Currently the Laravel [source uses new](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L743) so you might need to submit an idea to change this in https://github.com/laravel/ideas but (in theory) you can create a base model class of your own and override the `newRelatedInstance` function and have all your models extend your own overriden model.

Comment: but in a relationship context you need to tell the ORM which class is on the other end, since interfaces are not classes, i don't understand what you are trying to do. Because you need to tell an concrete class and interfaces are anything but concrete.

Comment: @mrhn What I am trying to achieve is to decouple two models that belong to different modules, but have a certain relationship, using interfaces. (this is quite common in other frameworks). For example in symfony you can use a `ResolveTargetEntityListener`. Developing using abstractions instead of concrete classes is practically indispensable to reduce coupling, so I think it should be extrapolated to eloquent relations.

Comment: @apokryfos I will take a look to your links when I get home. Thank you

Comment: I feel like you are trying to do another design filosophy in a framework that does not want you down that path. But wouldnt a static call that called your binding and got the class from that work? public static getClass () { return get_class(resove(Userable::class));}

Comment: @mrhn Its very possible that you are right with respect to the architecture that I intend to achieve, however Im of the opinion that, although it can be complicated, we should not conform to everything that the framework imposes (directly or indirectly), as developers we have to find the necessary tools to adapt it, as far as possible, to our needs. Probably the easiest option for me would be to use symfony; but I firmly believe that our only limitation is the language (PHP), so I see it possible to use Laravel to achieve, always with good practices, the objectives we want to achieve

Comment: @mrhn Regarding what you indicate about the static method, it seems to me an interesting idea. That method could go perfectly in a class that I have called SharedContext, whose responsibility is to manage the systems that the different modules share. I like it, I'll try it as soon as I get home and tell you something. Thank you :-)

Comment: In regards to following framework im on the go with the framework style :) but i write up an answer to what you can do.

Comment: @mrhn It works perfectly. Finally I have chosen to overwrite the Eloquent class and each of the classes that represent the different types of relationship (HasMany, BelongsTo, ...). In this way, within each constructor of these classes, I can search (resolve) for the implementation of the abstraction received. It works like a charn :-)

Comment: In fact, I have tried to remove a module and my whole system still works, returning an empty Builder (or collection).

Comment: I wrote up the answer i suggested, if it helped you can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you want with a static function call, placed somewhere in your app.

```
public static getClass () {
    return get_class(resolve(Userable::class));
}
```

This will solve your problem, as you can now bind the class and resolve it at run time.

Comment: Thank you very much, your comment served as inspiration to achieve the solution